# How to know if an variable exist in url even thou it dont have any value in php

Tags: php

Previously I used to add an value like `?help=1` to make PHP know that variable `help` is used and now it has to show help page. But on a few sites, I have seen they simply use only variables and do not assigned any value (i.e just `?help`). Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: better use url rewrite

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's isset function:

```
  if(isset($_GET['help']))
  {
  echo $_GET['help'];
  }
  else
  {
  echo "help is not set";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `isset($_GET["help"])`?

Answer (score 0):

This just means the variable 'help' exists, but has no value. If you maybe left a field blank on a form, it may do this simply so the next script can acknowledge it has no value rather than ignored. It works exactly the same way.